# How to get the row number of selected row in gridview?

Tags: .net, winforms, devexpress

Hi im a new devexpress user.
My question is how can I get the row number of the selected row in a gridview..

Comment: Although i've never used the DevExpress GridView, i think it enables to select more than one row(default). So which row-number do you want to have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views identify their rows by **row handles** (for instance, the [GridView.FocusedRowHandle](http://help.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_FocusedRowHandletopic.aspx) property specifies the focused row by its handle). Visible rows can also be identified by their **visible indexes** within a View. 
Views provide methods to convert row handles to visible indexes and vice versa. The [GridView.GetVisibleIndex](http://help.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetVisibleIndextopic.aspx) and [GridView.GetVisibleRowHandle](http://ColumnView.GetVisibleRowHandle) methods are used for this purpose.
You can read more about identiying rows here: [Identifying Rows and Cards](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument642)

Answer (score 0):

the event `SelectedIndexChanging` has an adhoc property for that called `NewSelectedIndex`

more info at :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedrow.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Visual Basic

```
Dim intRowNumber As Integer = CType(YourGridView.SelectedRow, GridRowView).RowIndex
```

Comment: Problem Solved I used this code `code` RowIndex = GridView1.FocusedRowHandle

Comment: @user1134480: Then post your solution as answer and accept it later.

Comment: @user1134480: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189 Click on the questionmark  and you'll get more informations on formatting(f.e. by clicking `Code` next).